# Query to delete first added element by a topic when it exceeds provided limit

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-delete

I have a table with 5 columns, one of the columns is **topic**. I need a query that will **delete** the row I added first (**oldest**) when I **group** it by topic.

I have an id column which is set as the primary key, however the increment(although it's all unique) is not reliable because of the way the data is getting filled with my python code.

This is for a SQLite database

```
DELETE FROM news where topic = "world"
```

The obvious issue with the above query is that it will delete everything when the `topic = world`, I only want to delete my oldest addition to the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery.  You have specified the "oldest", so I assume there is some type of date/time column with this information:

```
DELETE FROM news n
    WHERE n.topic = 'world' AND
          n.datetimecol = (SELECT MIN(n2.datetimecol)
                           FROM news n2
                           WHERE n2.topic = n.topic
                          );
```

If not, you can use an auto-incremented primary key.

Comment: There isn't a time column and all the data is input almost simultaneously. So is there any other way to do it, or will i have to somehow get some time column in there.

Comment: @rishi . . . You can use the existing id if it is auto-incremented.

Comment: It seems it doesn't autoincrement in order, because of some weird python thing, but I suppose I can just find the smallest number amongst them, as it doesn't have to be super precise according to my requirements.

Comment: @rishi . . . If you don't know which is the oldest, then you cannot delete the oldest.  Either the information is in the database or it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Same as other answerer said, there must be some `date_time` column. You can use not exists based on it as follows:

```
DELETE FROM news n
    WHERE n.topic = 'world'
      AND not exists
         (SELECT 1 FROM news nn
           WHERE nn.topic = n.topic
             AND nn.datetimecol < n.datetimecol);
```